# Scala Swing: Key events not firing?

Tags: swing, scala

I am trying to make an application respond to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> press. But no matter how I try modifying the code, it never fires.

```
// ...
val inputAndButtons = new BorderPanel {
  layout(inputScroll) = Center
  layout(buttons) = South
}
contents = new BorderPanel {
  layout(drawScn) = North
  layout(homeScroll) = Center
  layout(inputAndButtons) = South
  focusable = true
  requestFocus
  listenTo(keys, drawScn.keys, homeScroll.keys, inputArea.keys, buttons.keys, lambdaButton, harpoonButton, runButton)
  reactions += {
    case KeyPressed(_, Key.Enter, m, _) => {
      if (m == Key.Control || m == Key.Shift) runCode()
    }
    case ButtonClicked(component) => {
      if (component == lambdaButton) insertAtCaret("λ")
      if (component == harpoonButton) insertAtCaret("↼")
      if (component == runButton) runCode()
    }
  }
}
// ...
```

I have tried to find and implement an answer, but to no avail.

Details (in case you need them):

Scala 2.10.2, using SBT 0.13.1, on Ubuntu 13.10

**Edit:** The modifier is a number, which means that comparing it to a value from the Keys enum will always produce false. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has a value of 128, and the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key has a value of 64. Hence, the correct way to determine whether either key was pressed is `if ((m & 0xC0) == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with `if ((m & 0xC0) != 0)`.